# how to call Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, nested, ctypes

I am running a program darknet.py from within my ubuntu terminal by typing `python3 darknet.py`.

It works perfectly and now I am trying to include it in my own program. But when I call it I get errors. I am not sure what is causing this.

I have already included `#!usr/bin/env python3` but no luck. 
I am trying to call it with `os.systems('/home/bob/DarknetAB/darknet/darknet.py')`
The errors I get are as follows

```
from:cant read /var/mail/cytpes
import -im6.q16: not authorized math@error/constitute.c/writeImage1037
```

I don't know get why it would work from terminal, but not when I call it from another file?

Comment: you have to import the file, besides giving the `os.systems` look into `os.path`. otherwise check file permissions.

Comment: If I execute `from` in bash, I get a similar error. It sounds like the script is executed by your shell. You want to execute it explicitly with Python instead. By the way, replace `#!usr/bin/env` by `#!/usr/bin/env`. (Absolute paths start with a slash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [from: cant read /varmail/ctypes when called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503931/from-cant-read-varmail-ctypes-when-called)

Comment: Thanks so much for all advice. Comment below got it. I needed to add python3 at the start of my file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do the following?

```
import darknet
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but it sounds like it could be trying to read your python script like a bash one instead. What about

```
os.system('python3 /home/bob/DarknetAB/darknet/darknet.py')
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks so much! That works. Funny how long I have been looking at this and I forgot this one simple thing! You are a star!

Comment: Happy to be able to answer your question.